# Installing library plugins / binaries on AWS Lambda

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to use an audio library plugin system called [Vamp](https://www.vamp-plugins.org/) in an AWS Lambda runtime. Installed Vamp plugins are utilised via a Vamp host, like [Sonic Annotator](https://www.vamp-plugins.org/sonic-annotator/). To run a Vamp plugin via a host like Sonic Annotator in an AWS Lambda function, I think I need to do something like in [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/processing-user-generated-content-using-aws-lambda-and-ffmpeg/) tutorial i.e., package Sonic Annotator plus my Vamp plugin in a zip, which gets uploaded as an AWS Lambda layer. Or would I only do this for Sonic Annotator? The tutorial above uses Amazon Linux. On Linux, Vamp plugins are installed like [this](https://www.vamp-plugins.org/download.html?platform=linux64&search=key&go=Go#install):

> Put plugins for all users to use in /usr/local/lib/vamp

How would I setup / install my Vamp plugin and host (Sonic Annotator) in the context of AWS Lambda? Would the Vamp plugin that usually goes into a library folder be an AWS layer, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

For complex dependencies, the best way would be to use [container lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html). For this you would create a **docker image** with your application and all its dependencies, and then used as lambda function.

This is much easier and more flexible than traditional setup of lambda with a zip deployment file and/or lambda layers. On top of that, you get **10 GB** of space for your app and its dependencies, rather then 250 MB as doing this the old way.

Comment: @eartoolbox How did it go? The issue persists?